# Django + backgroundtask + AWS Elasticbeanstalk times out to deploy

Tags: django, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to use Django-background-tasks on my Django projekt. Now, I want elastic beanstalk to run the process_tasks, so I added a cron job config file. This is read by the server, but deployment times out eventually without delivering an error. If I ssh into my EC2 and use type in the commands below it works. Does anyone know why this might be a problem?

```
commands:
  processtasks:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && source /opt/python/current/env && cd /opt/python/current/app && python manage.py process_tasks"
```

Comment: Have you checked `eb-activity.log` file

Comment: It just stops, after: [2020-05-19T12:41:14.635Z] INFO  [3993]  - [Application update app-200519_144027@551/AppDeployStage0/EbExtensionPreBuild] : Starting activity...

Comment: If you are using `eb deploy` comment then try `eb deploy --timeout 20` where 20 is minutes, which increase elastic beanstalk timeout time.

Comment: Why you are adding the command process_tasks explicitly to run with the deployment process? Shouldn't it be in your cron job config file?

Comment: Hi! I am running into a similar issue. Did you ever figure this out?